# Abstract generic overlaps with non generic of base class

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following base classes

The non-generic:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public abstract bool DoMagic(string str1, string str2);
}
```

The generic class, inheriting from the non-generic:

```
public abstract class Foo<T> : Foo
{
    public abstract bool DoMagic(T t1, T t2);
}
```

Now I want to implement this class

```
public class FooNumeric : Foo<int>
{
    public override bool DoMagic(string str1, string str2) => true;
    public override bool DoMagic(int int1, int int2) => true;
}
```

Everything works as excepted as you can see here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/kWQUl9

Now I would like to not use `int` as the generic constraint but instead `string`.

```
public class FooString : Foo<string>
{
    public override bool DoMagic(string str1, string str2) => true;
    //public override bool DoMagic(string int1, string int2) => true;
}
```

But I can't seem to satisfy the compiler and I keep getting the error

> 'FooString' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Foo.DoMagic(string, string)'

https://dotnetfiddle.net/rfncTE

I have tried a couple of things, but to no success.

Is this possible?

Solutions I know that could fix this

1. Use the non-generic class on `FooString`

   Can't do this because `Foo<T>` contains many more generic methods and I have this overlapping on only one occasion.
2. Rename the method

   if possible I would like to stick to the names.

Comment: This is an unfortunate wart where inheritance and overloading don't play nice together. Note that you don't even need `Foo` to demonstrate the problem, `Foo<T>` (with both methods) is enough on its own. If `Foo` and `Foo<T>` were interfaces, this would just work.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - I hoped that one method could satisfy both base classes

Comment: No, because method slots do not work that way for classes. They *do* work that way for interfaces. Because `Foo<string>` can have only *one* entry for `DoMagic(string, string)` (regardless of what it's inheriting), only one of the methods can effectively be implemented. I believe C# is just transparently relaying the IL restriction here (though don't quote me on that, maybe it's more flexible than I recall) -- the compiler could of course work around it in the background with some renaming magic so it works anyway (at least within C#, possibly not other .NET languages), but it doesn't.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/5775

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the method that receives generic type parameters (`DoMagic(T, T)`) should have a more general name than a corresponding method that receives concrete types (e.g. `DoMagic(string, string)`). It is not just that you have a syntactic collision, but you also have a semantical collision in a sense that general and particular concepts share the same name.

Here is one naming scheme where a more concrete method (receiving `string`) has a more specific name, telling that it will do stuff *with* the strings.

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public bool DoMagic(T a, T b) { ... }
}

public class FooString : Foo<string>
{
    public bool DoMagicWith(string a, string b) { ... }
}
```

Another naming scheme is to note that general method (receiving the generic type parameter) is performing an operation with a wider definition than any method with concrete parameter types:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public bool DoAnyMagic(T a, T b) { ... }
}

public class FooString : Foo<string>
{
    public bool DoMagic(string a, string b) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, was afraid that this will be my only option.

Comment: My point is that this is the *good* option. Your original design is, in my opinion, unclear, because it is mixing up the levels of detail.